# Почему connection = null?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Начинаю изучать работу с *JDBC*.
Не могу понять, почему выходит ошибка, как будто невозможна инициализация `connection`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "this.serverVariables" is null     
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3005)   
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1916)     
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1845)   
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)  
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)    
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2106)
```

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Пытаюсь учить по ютубу.

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Userz/?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        final String USERNAME = "root";
        final String PASSWORD = "TestJDBC";

        Connection connection;
        DriverManager driverManager;
        Driver driver;


        try {
            driver = new Driver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connection");
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: на глаз мне кажется, что сам класс Connection должен быть имапортирован не из com.mysql.jdbc.Connection , а из java.sql.Connection; по крайней мере попробуйте

Comment: сейчас попробую) спасибо!

Comment: пока также валится с такой же ошибкой.(

Comment: да, еще у вас слеш лишний после имени базы данных Userz/? , а должно быт так Userz?

Comment: спасибо! сейчас поправлю этот момент

Comment: вообще урл кривой, прбуйте так: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Userz?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true

Comment: спасибо за нормальный урл. Но пока та же ошибка осталась.

Comment: а с какой строки кода она выпадает?System.out.println("Connection"); - эта строка отрбатывает? удалите свою бд и запустите программу, этот код сам создаст бд

Comment: нет, строка с распечатыванием текста не отрабатывает, выпадает ошибка на строке в трай-кетч connection = ....

Comment: сейчас добавлю ответ с кодом, который у меня работает. если у вас не работает, то проверяйте, установлен ли и запущен ли mysql, корректные ли данные для подключения. снесите бд и пусть сама программа ее пересоздаст. каким драйвером и версией мускула пользуетесь? по крайней мере этот код работает у меня так что гарантировано проблема не в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
    import java.io.Closeable;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    
    public class MySqlConnector implements Closeable {
    
        private final Connection connection;
    
        public MySqlConnector(String url, Integer port, String dbName, String username, String password) {
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://"+url+":"+port+"/"+dbName+"?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&"
                    + "requireSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true";
            this.connection = createConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
        }
        
        public Connection getConnection() {
            return connection;
        }
    
        private Connection createConnection(String url, String username, String password) {
            try {
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
                return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (MySqlConnector mySqlConnector = new MySqlConnector("localhost", 3306, "userz", "root", "TestJDBC")) {
            Connection connection = mySqlConnector.getConnection();
            System.out.println(connection);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо!